# Feature service misalignment in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-server, coordinate-system, arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api, feature-service

I have an issue with feature layers in ArcGIS Online. I am adding an ArcGIS Server web service witch creates a feature layer and then I add the feature layer in a web map. There are 11 layers in the feature layer. When I try to open the webmap I get a message that a layer is not responding

[image: layer not responding]

[image: misplaced water network]

This is a water network map. As you can see the pipes are misaligned and some pipes are missing. 
When I use the Collector app and download the map for offline use, they get aligned properly and there is nothing missing.

On another instance if I use a map image Layer everything shows up OK.
The spatial reference is Greek Grid (2100)

I am using ArcMap 10.4, ArcGIS Server 10.4, the service details are as following (for one of the 11 layers)

```
Layer: ΔΙΚΛΕΙΔΕΣ ΠΕΖΟΔΡΟΜΙΟΥ (ID: 0)
View In:   ArcGIS Online map viewer
Name: ΔΙΚΛΕΙΔΕΣ ΠΕΖΟΔΡΟΜΙΟΥ
Display Field: FACILITYID
Type: Feature Layer
Geometry Type: esriGeometryPoint
Description: This dataset contains a collection of features that represent        the water distribution network in a community.
Definition Expression: N/A 
Copyright Text:
Default Visibility: true
MaxRecordCount: 5000
Supported Query Formats: JSON, AMF, geoJSON
Min Scale: 2000
Max Scale: 0
Supports Advanced Queries: true
Supports Statistics: true
Use Standardized Queries: true
Supports ValidateSQL: true
Supports Calculate: false
Extent:
XMin: 350329.08951833844
YMin: 4373931.874201424
XMax: 373356.6671507545
YMax: 4398354.849961676
Spatial Reference: 2100  (2100)

Drawing Info:Renderer:Simple Renderer:
Symbol:Picture SymbolLabel: 
Description:Transparency: 0
Labeling Info:Label Placement: esriServerPointLabelPlacementAboveRight
Label Expression: [code] 
Use Coded Values: true
Symbol:Color: [0, 0, 0, 255]
Background Color: [233, 255, 190, 255]
Outline Color: [0, 0, 0, 255]
Vertical Alignment: bottom
Horizontal Alignment: left
Right to Left: false
Angle: 0
XOffset: 0
YOffset: 0
Size: 8
Font Family: Arial
Font Style: normal 
Font Weight: normal
Font Decoration: none
Min. Scale: 500.0
Max. Scale: 0.0
Advanced Query Capabilities:
Supports Statistics: true
Supports OrderBy: true
Supports Distinct: true
Supports Pagination: true
Supports TrueCurve: false
HasZ: false
HasM: false
Has Attachments: false
HTML Popup Type: esriServerHTMLPopupTypeAsHTMLText
Type ID Field:
Fields:
too many to display
Templates:
too many to display
Drawing Tool: esriFeatureEditToolPoint
Capabilities: Create,Query,Update,Sync,Delete,Uploads,Editing
Sync Can Return Changes: true
Is Data Versioned: true
Supports Rollback On Failure: false
Supports ApplyEdits With Global Ids: false
Supported Operations:   Query   Apply Edits   Add Features   Update Features         Delete Features   Validate SQL   Generate Renderer   Return Updates
```

Edit:
The misalignment is not constant in all layers.

For example as shown in the image below the main pipes(the last layer) are misaligned whereas the secondary pipes (second from last) are aligned properly.

[image: varied alignment]

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: What is the maxRecordCount for the ArcGIS server web service? The default is 1000. Call the service from the web is different that work with collector in offline mode.

Comment: MaxRecordCount: 5000

Can the MaxRecordCount affect the alignment?

Comment: in the second image how many features you think you are?  Press F12 and find the call to the query method. Copy the rest call and open it in a new window. Change the parameter f to html.

Comment: Probably more than 5000, but even if i zoom to an extend that only a few features are displayed, the misalingnment is still there. I can post another image if it helps.

Comment: If are more than 5000 you must change the maxRecordCount to retrieved all the feature in a particular extent.

Comment: Another chance is set the visibility at a scale when you are sure that the features returned from the service is less than 5000.

Comment: This is a similar question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74548/maximum-number-of-record-returned-by-the-server-why-1000

Comment: I changed the maxRecordCount to 50000. Performance-wise it is ok, but the alignment problem remains. The thing that puzzles me is what happens in collector? If it is a projection issue, why is it fixed? If not, what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you share the url of your feature service?

Comment: I have already posted the content of the url in the OP.

Comment: I think it can be fixed with layer visibility range. You are trying to show to many features at a time. If it works offline it must work online.

Comment: The main pipes layer has 43000 features. Is there a limitation in AGOL?

Answer (score 0):

I Think the problem is the coordinate system of your ArcGIS server web service. If you use Arcgis Online basemaps your service should also use projection Web Mercator. Look at ESRI's AGOL help, [Basemap considerations](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/choose-basemap.htm).

Comment: As i mentioned in the original question,
"On another instance if i use a map image Layer everything shows up ok."
I have created a Webapp using the image layer and there is no problem.
The problem occurs when i use a feature service.
Am i missing something?

Comment: "On another instance if i use a map image Layer everything shows up ok." Are you using this image Layer as a basemap or added on top of AGOL basemaps?

Comment: It is added on top of AGOL Basemap.  I can post an image if it helps

Comment: Which basemap are you using in Collector app?

Comment: Topographic basemap, but it really doesn't matter, I have also used imagery

Comment: I would try to change the coordinate system of the ArcGIS server web service to EPSG 3857 to match AGOL. If that dont work I have no more ideas

Comment: I could do that and it would probably work, but not working in the national projection system is not an option. I can still use collector in offline mode, but that is not good practice.